# Importing profile images to members personal portrait in Plone

Tags: plone

I'm trying to bulk upload portrait images to member profiles. Using the getPersonalPortrait function of mtool, I find that the object (FSImage) doesn't have the "data" attribute as the portraits with portrait images uploaded (Image).

How should I proceed to upload images to these member portraits without existing profile photos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create *new* `OFS.Image()` objects for uploaded portraits:

```
from OFS.Image import Image

portrait = Image(id=user_login, title='', file=fportrait) 
membertool._setPortrait(portrait, user_login)
```

where `fportrait` is either an open file object or the image data as a string.

Comment: I think the proper approach should be to use changeMemberPortrait method of the portal_membership tool.